# Python: checking "is in" for a specific sub element in a list

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list of tuples of the following format:

```
list = [(var1, var2, var3). (var1, var2, var3), ...]
```

Is it possible to construct an `if var is in list` statement that only checks if `var` is specifically in one of the `var3` slots?

For example, given the following list:

```
list = [(1, 2, 3), (7, 8, 9)]
```

I want to be able to check `if var is in List` in such a way that it will be true if `var == 3` but NOT true if `var == 2` since it's only checking a ***specific position*** in each tuple.

Comment: You could do `if var in (x[2] for x in list)`

Comment: Never name your variables as the language keywords - `list` in your sample code.

Comment: @vaultah this is really useful. Much thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
if any(x[2] == var for x in l)
```

(p.s: don't name your variable `list` since you override the built-in type)

Comment: This is perfect, Thanks! And yeah the actual name will be something more descriptive, "node_list" etc

Answer (score 4):

You can use the built-in [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
>>> lst = [(1, 2, 3), (7, 8, 9)]
>>> any(v3==3 for *_, v3 in lst)
True
```

It short-circuits once a match is found so you don't need to iterate over the entire list.

Can be extended to Python 2 (since extended unpacking will not work):

```
any(v3==3 for _, _, v3 in lst)
```

Comment: `*_, v3` is cute.

Comment: @amarnath The Python 3 solution will always go for the last item, so yes.

Comment: If you need a python 2 solution you could do `any(x[-1]==3 for x in lst)` and you just want the last item and you aren't sure of the sizes of tuples.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following trick to get a list of all the var1 values, a list of all var2 values, and a list of all var3 values:

```
var1s, var2s, var3s = zip(*list)
```

Then you simply check `if var is in var3s`.